# Registering any click in Jquery outside a menu element to toggle it hidden

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, click

I have created a simple drop down in my system for order which appears upon clicking an element just below it. I can toggle the menu hidden below it by clicking that element again. But I would like to catch clicks outside after that other than the options in the drop down itself to hide it so users can easily discard it if needs be. Is there an easy way in jQuery to achieve this. All im simply using at the moment for the toggling is clicks on a  element which states the current order to hide and reveal with .is(':hidden').

Appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: The general idea is to bind a click handler on the document, but to give you the specific syntax you'll have to show your markup.

Answer (score 1):

Think ive actually answered my own question.

Discovered stopPropagation() and then bind checks on $('html').click() to see if element is(':visible') and hide();

Thanks for the help guys.